# How do I make an object in Google Cloud Storage accessible via a link but require a key or some other form of verification to access it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am creating an application that requires a file to be retrived from a Google Cloud Storage bucket. Right now, I have the file's public access set to true so I can access it via URL.

Is it possible to still access the file via URL, but require some sort of authentication in the form of a key etc.?

I have looked through how IAM permissions work; however, I am not confident in my ability to use such tools proficiently yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not currently available.

One possible workaround would be to write your own small service that accepts whatever custom authorization or keys you like and then vends a short-lived signed URL as a redirection. So the user would send GET to https://yourservice.com/download?magicKey=12345, and then your service would evaluate it and maybe reply with a 304 to https://storage.googleapis.com/yourbucket/yourobject?elaborateSignedUrl, with the signed URL limited to just a minute or two of validity. This would solve your problem but would require writing and maintaining the URL vending service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a permission on a single object on Cloud Storage. The correct way to achieve that is to have a service, that check the permission of the user and the right to access the object.

If the user can access it and want to download it, you can generate a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) and send it to the user. With this URL, the user can download the file in a secure way (the bucket is not public and only the Signed URL can access the file, for a limited period of time)